# Understanding "Multiplication/ Group Operation" in Fractional Experiments

Tags: experiment-design, confounding, fractional-factorial

There's a group operation, at least of sorts, in Fractional Factorial design that I'm trying to understand. For definiteness, let's say we have 3 factors; A,B,C , at two levels each . Please critique my understanding. We assume Sparsity of Effects, so that the compound ABC is insignificant. Then we somehow set ABC=1. Just what is this 1? Are we somehow "multiplying" or composing A with B, with C in order to arrive to this 1? Can we define a multiplication around this relation alone and the aliasing, where columns with equal signs are equivalent?
Edit: I assume the "1", stands for an insignificant result, and other relations are given through aliasing, i.e., pairs of  combinations( apologies, I'm drawing a blank on the precise terminology here)are deemed equal if their columns are equal, e.g., AB=C, for each of their column entries. Is this it, or is there more to it, like a formal Mathematical description?